# MEV bots contract addresses

Tags: gas, frontrunning, mev, bot

how so many MEV bots contract addresses start with many zeros?
I understand they do so to use less gas but how they manage to create contracts with such addresses?

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are using `CREATE2` for deploying the contracts and brute force to figure out what salt to use to get the leading `0`s.

Address for contracts created using `CREATE2` are determined as `keccak256( 0xff ++ address ++ salt ++ keccak256(init_code))[12:]`. Within these 3 parameters, `address` and `init_code` would be fixed, salt can be changed for getting different output, so brute force the salt to get a desired pattern in your address.

Check the EIP at https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014